# the unique ID primary key within SQL - can it be auto assigned

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for some advice regarding the following ...

regarding "weather forecasts"

I have a csv file containing columns for (today's) date, time (forecast) date, time, temperature forecast

Column A will have several rows with today's date and Column B: the time the forecast was acquired, then for each row the hourly temperature forecasts for the next 24 to 36 hours with a columns for the starting hour and a column for the ending hour and then the forecasted temperature.

This csv is automatically appended daily.

I would like to import this csv file into sql and then keep this sql database updated.

Regading the (daily) csv file - There is not a really good unique id

No column will be unique.

I am using MYSQL (workbench).

I'm looking for some advice:

Can MySQL automatically take care of the unique primary key?

I see that I can manually add a columns of sequential number (now / one time) and import into MySQL

But what about tomorrow and so on when the csv is appended,

Is there a more automated way to handle unique Primary keys?

Next, thoughts on making this whole process automated or semi-automated? - that is keeping a SQL database updated with this weather forecast data from an appended csv?
Thanks

Comment: That's too long of a question.

Comment: Google for MySQL AUTOINCREMENT, and you should find all you need!

Comment: Yes. this is AUTOINCREMENT. But.. your key can be compound too, like Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D describe your unique record. It seems like that would be a more sensical choice to enforce uniqueness, right?

Comment: Date time seems like one possibility

Comment: Thank you all - I can't really use just the date - I have several rows with the same date - I am going to read up on the AUTOINCREMENT and chase concatenate (compounding) some columns together for the id

Answer (score 2):

Look over here for auto increment.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

You will need to use: `AUTO_INCREMENT`

It will be wise to use a unique id for each row and for calling purpose you can use the other keys.

Comment: Professional rivalry perhaps, but see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com

Comment: @Strawberry Yeah, I know. Referring w3 schools is not a good idea. But I just wanted him to learn the basics of `auto_increment`. And I always feel that there should only one column in the primary key so that calling a row becomes easier and in that way the complexity of the queries also get reduced.